# Why does AutoFixture's AutoMoqData not create mock objects?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, moq, autofixture

I am writing ([NUnit](http://nunit.org/)) unit tests that target a component of type `MyService`. Example:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IMyRepo _myRepo;

    public MyService (IMyRepo myRepo)
    {
        _myRepo = myRepo;
    }

    public MyService ()
    {
        _myRepo = new MyRepo();
    }
    ...
}
```

I am trying to use [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) as a [factory](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/02/13/SUTFactory/) that will generate my test target. I am also trying to have it (AutoFixture) populate my target with mock dependencies (using [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4)).

Here's my attempt at doing this:

```
[Test, AutoMoqData]
public void MyTest(MyService target)
{
    ...
}
```

The `[AutoMoqData]` attribute (based on [@ploeh's blog post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/08/AutoDataTheorieswithAutoFixture/)) extends AutoFixture's `[AutoData]` attribute with AutoFixture's `AutoMoqCustomization` feature:

```
public class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoMoqDataAttribute()
        : base(new Fixture()
            .Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization()))
    {
    }
}
```

When I run unit tests based on the above, I would like to get a real instance of `MyService` with a `Mock<IMyRepo>` dependency inside it. 
Instead I'm getting a concrete instance of `MyRepo`.

It seems that `AutoMoqCustomization` opts to invoke the simplest constructor - the one with no arguments. **How can I configure `AutoMoqCustomization`to ignore it and instead instantiate the second constructor**?

**PS -** Here is a list of the relevant nuget packages in use:

   `<package id="AutoFixture" version="3.50.2" targetFramework="net452" />
   <package id="AutoFixture.AutoMoq" version="3.50.2" targetFramework="net452" />
   <package id="AutoFixture.NUnit3" version="3.50.2" targetFramework="net452" />
   <package id="Moq" version="4.5.29" targetFramework="net452" />
   <package id="NUnit" version="3.5.0" targetFramework="net452" />`

Comment: Please list your NuGet package dependencies.

Comment: Please post steps to reproduce. How are you observing that the dependency is not what you'd like it to be?

Comment: Thanks @MarkSeemann. Just tried a minimal repro in a new project and now it works. Will update soon.

Comment: Ouch. I've found that `MyService` has an empty constructor with `_myRepo = new MyRepo()` in it. Now rephrasing my question in view of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to [define a greedy constructor selection algorithm for AutoFixture](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/04/19/ConstructorstrategiesforAutoFixture), but really, the best solution is to remove the parameterless constructor:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IMyRepo _myRepo;

    public MyService (IMyRepo myRepo)
    {
        _myRepo = myRepo;
    }
}
```

Having a parameterless constructor is a code smell called **Bastard Injection**. In most cases, there's no good reason for it.

In my opinion, the best option is to apply the [GOOS](http://amzn.to/VI81bP) principle of listening to your tests. When the test becomes difficult to write, it's time to reconsider the design of the System Under Test (SUT). AutoFixture tends to amplify this effect. That's what's happening here.

Comment: Many thanks for the super-quick solution. Indeed the empty ctor is a code smell: `[Obsolete("Please don't use this ctor. Only in use for old static classes being phased out.", false)]`. Working diligently on clearing it up :)
`